# jni.h: no such file or direcotory on chroot ubuntu

Tags: java, c++, ubuntu, makefile, chroot

In the makefile, the path is given:

```
 JAVA_HOME=/srv/schroot/precise_i386/usr/java

 INCLUDES=-I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/ -I. -I/usr/include/freetype2/

 CFLAGS=-ansi -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strength-reduce -g -Wall -DLINUX=1 $(INCLUDES)


 mytarget.o:
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c mytarget.cpp -o mytarget.o
```

But when I compile the code, I get jni.h: no such file or directory. 
I also tried to give the full path to jni.h in the code:

```
 #include </srv/chroot/precise_i386/usr/java/include/jni.h>
```

not work either. 
I am sure the jni.h file is there.

Anyone knows why? Thanks.

LJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you why it won't work, you should make some tests.
something like this:

```
mytarget.o:
      ls -l $(JAVA_HOME)  
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c mytarget.cpp -o mytarget.o
```

Now check if the ls is working properly, if not, maybe some spelling error in the path? or un-mapped network file-system? if it works continue to the include:

```
ls -l $JAVA_HOME/include
```

and finally to the file

```
ls -l $JAVA_HOME/include/jni.h
```

If all ls are working and still can't find the header it is really weird.

**EDIT**: you should also try:

```
#include "jni.h"
```

instead of:

```
#include <jni.h>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried ls -l $(JAVA_HOME)/include/jni.h,  I got no such file or directory. The problem is because I use chroot. The path I set should be /usr/java, instead of /srv..../java/. Thanks again.